# How to annotate Django Queryset with the same value but with a different data type of one of existing fields?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-annotate

I have a `Django model` that has a `NumberVal` field which is `models.FloatField()`.

Then I need to annotate the `queryset` objects like so
.`annotate(numberval_as_text=str(OuterRef("NumberVal")))` - the same value, but as a string except for the fact that this throws `QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s): OuterRef(NumberVal)` error which is clearly right but it demonstrates the point.

I need this because this annotation is followed by an extensive second annotation where I need this `numberval_as_text` in subquery filters.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `str` on an object obviously will give you a string representation of the object, hence you get the error. If one wants to type case something, they can use the [`Cast` database function [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/database-functions/#cast):

```
from django.db.models import CharField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast


queryset.annotate(numberval_as_text=Cast(OuterRef("NumberVal"), output_field=CharField(max_length=256)))
```

> **Note**: Unless this annotation is in a subquery, you want to use `F("NumberVal")` (`from django.db.models import F`) instead of
> `OuterRef("NumberVal")`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `OuterRef`. You can just use plain cast with annotation.

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.functions import Cast


qs.annotate(numberval_as_text=Cast('NumberVal', output_field=models.CharField()))
```